# Mysql auth issues client and server side

Tags: mysql, node-mysql2

Im trying to connect to a mysql 5.0.95 database via node-mysql2, but according to node-mysql its a bad handshake, and according to node-mysql2 it is :

> "Error: Server requests authentication using unknown plugin . See
>   TODO: add plugins doco here on how to configure or author
>   authentication plugins."

The github for mysql2 references a unsupported sha-256 authentication plugin but the error specifies the plugin as such, mine just says "." instead.

I have tried creating a new user on the mysql database, but if i try to create a new user with

```
CREATE USER 'username'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password'
```

it fails with

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password'' at line
>   1

The WITH option causes a syntax error and cant be used for some reason. Anyone have any idea what i can do to get some node mysql driver to connect to this database?